# TZ environment variable not persisting

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I want to change my date format to IST format for `date` command in terminal and system time.
`date` command shows in IST format after I change it but it doesn't persist new terminal tab or system reboot even when I have already put environment variable for that in `.bash_profile` file.

[image]

[image]

On new tab:

[image]

Other settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Next time please do not post pictures of text. It's really hard to read

Answer (score 3):

Use `timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Kolkata`. Then reboot.

After rebooting, the new default timezone should be in effect system-wide.

Setting the TZ variable in `.bash_profile` only affects that particular user, and you'll need to logout & login to make it take effect. A new terminal tab is not necessarily equivalent of a new login.

Comment: Putting variables in `.bashrc` file worked for me unlike `.bash_profile` as said [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/633820).

Comment: Still, it affects only your login sessions, and I understood you wanted to change the timezone for the entire system. Any system services started by `systemd` will still use the system-wide default, unless you add the TZ variable to each service definition, and using `timedatectl`to change the default is easier than that.

Comment: @SunilKumarDas It works, but the right place to put all your environment variables is `~/.profile` under Debian based distro.